# Put a state on a column if an element change the state in a dataframe with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next dataframe with a lot of elements

| code | status | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Active | 1 |
| b | Inactive | 2 |
| c | Active | 3 |
| b | Active | 4 |
| a | Inactive | 7 |
| c | Active | 8 |

Is there anyway to create a dataframe with the next result

| code | status |
| --- | --- |
| a | change to inactive on June |
| b | change to active on april |
| c | no changes |

Or to have something like a report, It will be so helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. `sort_values` by the "code" and "Month" columns
2. Use `np.where` to assign actions when the status changes.
3. `drop_duplicates` to keep only final row for each "code"

```
df = df.sort_values(["code", "Month"])
df["status"] = (np.where((df["code"].eq(df["code"].shift())) & 
                         (df["status"].ne(df["status"].shift())), 
                         "change to "+df["status"].str.lower()+" in "+pd.to_datetime(df["Month"],format="%m").dt.strftime("%B"), 
                         "no changes")
                )

output = df.drop_duplicates("code", keep="last").drop("Month", axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

>>> output
  code                      status
0    a  change to inactive in July
1    b   change to active in April
2    c                  no changes
```

Comment: Awesome!. But for example can I put a condition in the shift statement?.
Like if it changes from inactive to active, display=Reactivate

Comment: @PaulCoder - Isn't "change to active" the exact same thing as "reactivate"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `join` on 'status' and 'month' and return a new dataframe. Then you can split and combine parts of those two columns (status and month), and lastly you can change the codes that had 'Active' in both occasions  with `loc` and the help of your grouped object:

```
# Convert Month and sort
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%m').dt.month_name()
df = df.sort_values(["code", "Month"])

>>> print(df)

  code    status     Month
0    a    Active   January
1    b  Inactive  February
2    c    Active     March
3    b    Active     April
4    a  Inactive      July
5    c    Active    August

# Groupby and join
g = df.groupby(['code']).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x))

>>> print(g)
              status           Month
code                                 
a     Active Inactive    January July
b     Inactive Active  February April
c       Active Active    March August

# Combine columns and replace to 'no change'
res = pd.DataFrame('change to ' + g.status.str.split(' ',1).str[1] + ' on ' + g.Month.str.split(' ',1).str[1],columns=['status'])
res.loc[res.index.isin(g[g.status.eq('Active Active')].index),'status'] = 'no change'

>>> print(res)

                          status
code                            
a     change to Inactive on July
b      change to Active on April
c                      no change
```

---

Sample DF:

```
{'code': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'b', 4: 'a', 5: 'c'},
 'status': {0: 'Active',
  1: 'Inactive',
  2: 'Active',
  3: 'Active',
  4: 'Inactive',
  5: 'Active'},
 'Month': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 7, 5: 8}}
```